Issue with creating iceberg table in aws datalake
I have a use case to read the data from oracle on prem to aws
datalake iceberg table .
Issue I am facing here is .
Our s3 bucket has an scp that denies put object operation if we don’t specify sse algorithm in our operation . So while creating the iceberg table it will automatically put iceberg metadata into s3 which causes error as we couldn’t pass the sse algorithm while generating the iceberg table .
Is there any workaround for this?
Tried to create table using Athena . It created table , but while writing data through glue job , we cloudnt pass sse algorithm and put operation failed for data
Tried to create the table through glue job.put exception got for not providing encryption option
